# Can I buy tickets for the ADO bus online, without a Mexican payment card?

Tags: buses, payment-cards, mexico

I saw somewhere that you can only buy tickets for the ADO Bus if you have a Mexican credit card. 
I did the full simulation and, apparently, they even accept Paypal, which in principle, should accept any major credit card I didn't pay yet as I am not sure of the travel dates yet, so I can't tell for sure.

Does someone have experience with this?
Can one buy an ADO bus ticket online without a Mexican payment card?

Comment: PayPal is often set to accept payments in a specific currency, and require a matching billing address. You wouldn't be able to supply a Mexico address with a foreign CC.  I live in Mexico and cannot use PayPal with a lot of Mexico merchants because my CC (and PayPal account) is not Mexican

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this when travelling in Mexico a year and a half ago. ADO's site simply will fail at processing non-Mexican payments. They are far from the only Mexican website that is very cautious with this: there is a very high rate of payment fraud in Mexico. I've even had my card blocked trying to book flights on Mexican airlines' sites for travel from the States and Canada.

Luckily, I happen to work at Busbud and we've since been able [partner up with ADO to offer many routes and accept international cards](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-company/ado) (and charge your card in your home currency if you prefer).

If we don't offer the route(s) you're trying to book let us know and we'll see what we can do.